# how to show jquery datepicker date in onload in to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

this script for load dates in to div onclick, i want show date in the div onload.
 this script for load dates in to div onclick, i want show date in the div onload

```
 <input id="datepicker2">
    <div id="date">
      <div id="day-number">
      </div>
      <div id="day-month">
        <div id="day-name">
        </div>
        <div id="month">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    

 var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
     var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'nov', 'Dec'];
     $(function() {
       $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
         onSelect: function(dateText) {
           var dateObj = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
           $('#day-name').html(days[dateObj.getDay()]);

           var dayNo = dateObj.getDate();

           if (dayNo.length == 1)
             $('#day-number').html('0' + dayNo);
           else
             $('#day-number').html(dayNo);
           $('#month').html(months[dateObj.getMonth()]);

         }
       }).datepicker("setDate", "0");

       $('#date').on("click", function() {
         $('#datepicker2').datepicker('show');
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, your `div` shall be straight filled with the date from `datepicker`?

```
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'nov', 'Dec'];

function showDate(value) {
  $('#day-name').html(days[value.getDay()]);
  var dayNo = value.getDate();
  if (dayNo.toString().length == 1)
    $('#day-number').html('0' + dayNo);
  else
    $('#day-number').html(dayNo);
  $('#month').html(months[value.getMonth()]);
}

$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    var dateObj = $("#datepicker2").datepicker('getDate');
    showDate(dateObj);
  }
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");

showDate($("#datepicker2").datepicker('getDate'));
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jd68tg4x/2/ - note JavaScript LOAD TYPE is "*onLoad*".

You don'even need your `onclick` handler, it's already handled by the `datepicker` itself.

Comment: gotchaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @AjeshKolakkadan: please see my edit - BTW, if you find one answer useful, don't forget to mark it as accepted. See here: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @AjeshKolakkadan: in my last edit i also adjusted the mistake with the dayNo length. It shall be dayNo.toString().length.

Answer (score 4):

Call the function inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker('show');
     });
```

This call would only be triggered after your elements defined in document are loaded.
if you want to delay it even further then call it in window.onload

```
function loadDatePicker() {
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker('show');
        }
        window.onload = loadDatePicker;
```

Or, if you want to do it by recursion i.e wait until the div is loaded and trigger it, try this :-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  checkContainer();
});

function checkContainer () {
  if($('#datepicker2').is(':visible'))){ //if the container is visible on the page
   $('#datepicker2').datepicker('show');
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkContainer, 100); //wait 100 ms, then try again
  }
}
```

Hope this helps, happy coding :)

Comment: thank sumodh nair, its not work  dear , can you please explain with a fiddle.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` can be simply replaced with `$(function() { ... })`.